# GD Library not working even though it is enabled in phpinfo()

Tags: ubuntu, php, gd

I am hoping someone here can give me some advice about why my GD Library does not seem to be working even though it is installed and enabled in phpinfo()

Here is a quick rundown of what I am using:

- PHP 5.5.16
- Ubuntu 12.04
- GD 2.1.1-dev (have tried other versions as
  well to no avail)

As I said gd shows up in phpinfo but it simply doesn't work.  I don't get an error.  Just a completely blank screen.  I have been trying everything I can think to do, but nothing I have tried has worked.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: As @MichaelHampton suggests, a blank screen on a PHP page almost always translates to a useful message in your logs.

Comment: I am looking in the error log and I do not see an error.  In the access log I see a status of 200.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to On in your php.ini file in (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini), restart Apache and refresh the page.  You should get some sort of meaningful error.

Create a separate php file with just `var_dump(gd_info());` and see what that returns.  If it returns info on gd library then it is more than likely a simple syntax error in the code.  I would suggest posting your code so we can have a look.